# Integer part times modulus

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is there a notation or formula on a,b are positive integers:
c=Int(a/b)*(a mod (b)) 
For example 
a=25
b=9
Int(25/9)=2
25 mod 9 =7
I am interested in 2*7=14.
Thanks
If there are papers on this, I am greatful for links, too.

Comment: Why do you want to research this? Is there anything you have looked at or read that made you want to ask this? By the way, you can write this as $\lfloor{a/b}\rfloor (a-b*\lfloor{a/b}\rfloor)$, since $\lfloor{a/b}\rfloor$ is the quotient of the expression.

Comment: Thanks. I am working on values of two dimensional matrices that derive from a and b and while working on it, my calculation lead to this formula where I meed to miltiply tha whole part and the modulus part of two whole numbers.

Comment: There's really not much you can do to simplify my expression other than to expand it, unless you state that $a$ has to be divisible by $b$.

Comment: Thank you for your help.